# OAuth approach in nativescript to jhipster spring social

Tags: oauth-2.0, nativescript, jhipster, spring-social

Short: How to configure jhipster/spring social to land on custom page containing status / jwt token instead of app homepage after OAuth handshake?

Long:

I am building an app that has a web and mobile version that talk to a jhipster back end.  I need to implement OAuth authentication in my mobile app.  I am using nativescript on front end (mobile app) and jhipster with jwt/social login on the back end.  I would like my app to authenticate with Facebook, Google, Twitter and possibly more providers.

There is a nativescript-oauth plugin but it currently will only support 1 provider (facebook, office360) per app instance and has no notion of a backend of any form.  This plugin's architecture has the client invoking the OAuth dance through the nativescript WebView and then it parses/scans results from the WebView to check success or failure.

I am attempting to achieve something similar with the jhipster social login.  I would like to invoke the Spring Social OAuth exchange through a nativescript WebView component that loads the /signin/ url in the jhipster app and then watch the WebView component to check for success or failure and get jwt token.

Can I configure jhipster/spring social to NOT land on home page after successful OAuth handshake but instead redirect to an empty or status page (jsp/thymleaf html) that I could scrape for success and jwt token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my answer to this is easily found in the application.yml file. There is a property: "jhipster.social.redirect-after-sign-in".  Just changed it to my custom page and it worked fine after social login.

Comment: Hi @bill-pfeiffer did you get login with Twitter (oauth 1a) working? looking for a NativeScript solution. Which plugin are you using?